# Why is my code running into an infinite loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, infinite-loop

I'm new to learning Python. I'm having trouble figuring out why my code is running into an infinite loop.

I'm just trying to print numbers using a while loop, and using a function to call the while loop.
I appreciate your help!

Here is the code:

```
numbers = []

def check_num(i, end_num):
    while i < end_num:
        print "At the top i is %d" % i
        numbers.append(i)

        i = i + 1
        print "Numbers now: ", numbers
        print "At the bottom i is %d" % i


k = raw_input(">")
check_num(0, k)

print "The numbers: "
print check_num

for num in numbers:
    print num
```

Answer (score 4):

`raw_input` gives you a string.

Change:

```
k = raw_input(">")
```

into:

```
k = int(raw_input(">"))
```

Because in Python 2 you can compare strings and numbers:

```
>>> 2 < '1'
True
```

Fortunately, this wont work in Python 3:

```
>>> 2 < '1'
...
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()
```

So in your case `end_num` is a string. Therefore, `i < end_num` will always be true no matter what the value of he integer `i` is. So, your loop:

```
while i < end_num:
```

will never terminate.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer makes sense to me, and the code works now!